# How to Finds The Smallest Number In Loop Scanner

Tags: java

Dears,

I need to find the Lowest number in the loop scanner. 0 to stop the program. The issue I phased is that every time the lowest will be 0. What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loop_Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=1;
        int largest = 0;
        int Lowest = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        if(x>0) {
            while (x != 0) {
                x = input.nextInt();
                if (largest<=x){
                    largest=x;
                } else if (Lowest >=x ) {
                    Lowest =x;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The Largest Number is: "+largest);
            System.out.println("The Smallest Number is: "+Lowest);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong Value");
        }
}}
```

Comment: Initialize `lowest` with a high number (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`),

Comment: An alternative way is to declare `lowest` as `Integer` instead of `int`, then initialise it as `null`. Then you can do `if (lowest == null || lowset >= x) { lowset = x; }` . Although this is more clunky than initialising `int lowset = Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it is better in term of meaning, i.e. when you mean it has no value, it really has no value.

Comment: `int lowset = Integer.MAX_VALUE` "lowset" Is it a wrong spill or its right?

Comment: Wrong spell, sorry for typo.

Answer (score 0):

on your code

```
else if (Lowest >=x ) {
            Lowest =x;
      }
```

Lowest value is always 0
because the lowest value is set to 0

set the first value to the lowest value

Comment: 0 is to stop the progeram and also it's the lowest number. any way to solve this issue? I tried to use the bigger from the lowest but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Lowest is relative. You can find the answer by comparing the next incoming values ​​based on the first entered value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my problem. Thank you all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Loop_Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=1;
        int largest = 0;
        int Lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        while (x != 0) {
            x = input.nextInt();
            if (x > 0) {

                if (largest <= x) {
                    largest = x;
                } else if (Lowest >= x) {
                    Lowest = x;
                } else if(x<0) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong Value");
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println("The Largest Number is: " + largest);
            System.out.println("The Lowest Number is: " + Lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the user enters a all signed (negative) integer numbers? It doesn't hurt to cover that as well. Change `int largest = 0;`  to  `int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Loop_Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        int largest = 0;
        int lowest = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
        while (x != 0) {
            x = input.nextInt();
            if (x < 0) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Value");
                continue;
            }
            if (largest <= x){
                largest = x;
            }
            if (lowest >= x ) {
                lowest = x;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Largest Number is: " + largest);
        System.out.println("The Smallest Number is: " + lowest);
    }
}
```